# Refactoring a Laravel Eloquent query

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, refactoring

How can I refactor something like this Eloquent query? I've read a lot about refactoring but could not find anything for this.

```php
public function trophy(Request $request)
{
    // get trophy model
    $trophy = Trophy::whereCommentID($request->comment_id)
        ->whereUserID(auth('api')->user()->id)->exists();

    // create if not exists
    if (!$trophy) {
        $Trophy = Trophy::create([
            'comment_id' => $request->comment_id,
            'user_id' => auth('api')->user()->id,
            'trophy_id' => $request->trophy
        ]);

        return $Trophy;
    }

    // remove trophy if already exists with same trophy id
    if ($trophy->trophy_id === $request->trophy_id) {
        $trophy->delete();

        return;
    }

    // change trophy id to new trophy id if not exists && was not same trophy id
    $trophy->trophy_id = $request->trophy_id;
    $trophy_id->save();

    return $trophy_id;
}
```

Comment: Another way to say refactor would be "change code to accomplish the same task." What change are you trying to make?

Comment: Why not use `firstOrCreate()` for your first and second snippet of code?

Comment: @ultrasamad thats right , but what about the 2 last part?

Comment: $trophy = Trophy::firstOrNew(
    ['comment_id' => '$request->comment_id'],
    ['user_id' => auth('api')->user()->id, 'trophy_id' => $request->trophy_id]
);

Comment: not 100% but you will also need $trophy->save(); it will be better for you than firstOrCreate so you can apply conditions before save to db

Comment: @AhmedAboud Guys any idea about the 2 last part?

Comment: With your last two part, what does trophy_id represnts. Is it an autoincrement? Why are you changing it?

Comment: @ultrasamad no its not

Answer (score 0):

```
$trophy = Trophy::updateOrCreate([
            'comment_id' => $commment_id,
            'user_id' => $user_id
        ], [
            'trophy_id' => $trophy_id
        ]);

return $trophy;
```

Comment: What about this man? `if ($trophy->trophy_id === $request->trophy_id) {
        $trophy->delete();

        return;
    }`